# replit and mongodb connection issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

i'm using replit to host my server and when i try to connect that server to the database i get this error

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 35.192.152.76:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-5w1u46w-shard-00-00.7i7mg2d.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-5w1u46w-shard-00-01.7i7mg2d.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-5w1u46w-shard-00-02.7i7mg2d.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 35.192.152.76:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-5w1u46w-shard-00-00.7i7mg2d.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-5w1u46w-shard-00-01.7i7mg2d.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-5w1u46w-shard-00-02.7i7mg2d.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-l84o5l-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

when i set the connection access to all IP's it works fine , but when i put the same IP that i get in the error messege it doesnt work.

i restart the db but still nothing changes

Comment: You must whitelist **your** IP-Address, `35.192.152.76` is the IP of the server you like to connect to.

Comment: i did and it didnt work